# Linux Mint 19 Local DNS resolution problem

Tags: dns, linux-mint

I installed **Linux Mint 19** after using Ubuntu for a while,

I a have a local domain with subdomains, 
I can ping **mydomain.local**

but I can't ping or access my subdomains with their names,

my DNS server IP = 10.0.0.4

Here's my **/etc/resolv.conf** generated with **resolvconf**:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 10.0.0.4
```

And here's my **/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf** :

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 10.0.0.4
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in the file **/etc/nsswitch.conf** in the line :

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

remark the "**dns**" is after the "**[NOTFOUND=return]**" part, so that is why the DNS resolution is not going correctly, so what I have done is moving "dns" before "[NOTFOUND=return]" part, and everything is good now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Mint expert, don't know if I can help, but I'll certainly try...  It's a bit 'blind leading the blind' in support forums :/

I recently installed Mint 19 but the only DNS issues I've had were caused by systemd's resolver.  I have since replaced it with `unbound`.

I used this guy's instructions and it worked perfectly fine for me. YMMV.

https://blobfolio.com/2017/05/fix-linux-dns-issues-caused-by-systemd-resolved/

tl;dr: With systemd-resolve, LLMNR is used for short name resolution, which doesn't failover to a canonicalised DNS resolution.  LLMNR is tried a few times and then it just fails without touching DNS.

I think there's a severe bug in it, TBQH - Others agree.  Systemd's resolver behaves in an unexpected and possibly standards-breaking way and has done for 3-4 years.

HTH :D