# Linux (Mint) doesn't resolve IP of local NAS

Tags: dns, linux-mint

After upgrading from Linux Mint 18.3 to 19.3 I now experience a problem.
(I just tried and reproduced the same problem with a fresh installation of Linux Mint 20)

I can ping external websites with their names, the IP address is resolved perfectly.
But pinging my NAS, my printer or other (windows) PCs in my network by their names fails:

> $ping rnas
> ping: rnas: Name or service not known

I found this article: [Linux Mint 19 Local DNS resolution problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268016/linux-mint-19-local-dns-resolution-problem) but it doesn't help me.

Anyone?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
instead or pinging "rnas" I have to ping "rnas.local".
Sorry for the noob question.